# How do we find the origin of Gossip?

Tags: l5r-4e, social-combat

Samurai in power have boring days. Like, get up, train a few hours, answer letters, order some commoners to be executed, then spend the afternoon trading gossip...

Now, gossip isn't generally attached with a nametag attached who told it the first time. And you generally at times want to try to find out the source of the gossip...

Our GM ruled in the first instance we tried to find such a gossip source, that Courtier (Gossip) might be the best fit. However, Courtier is described as the *"social offense"*, and among its used, explains that this is to spread or find gossip about a person. The *"social defense"* is used at Etiquette, but that has specialisations on Bureaucracy, Conversation and Courtsey, at which point it gets wonky.

What is the correct roll to find the origin of a Gossip:

- [seeker's] Courtier(Gossip) vs. [source's] Etiquette (Conversation)
- [seeker's] Courtier(Gossip) vs. [source's original roll of] Courtier(Gossip)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of Etiquette is:

> Etiquette is essentially the “social defense” Skill of honorable characters in Rokugan’s courts. When someone tries to tempt, manipulate, or otherwise influence you (typically with skills like Courtier or Temptation), Etiquette is usually used in the ensuing Contested Roll

Nobody is trying to tempt, manipulate, or otherwise influence the person spreading gossip, just identify them.

---

Gossip meanwhile:

> Courtier can also be used to obtain or spread rumors about someone, using the Gossip Emphasis.

Someone using gossip to spread rumours skilfully will be able to plant the seeds so that it spreads through too many people to be traced back and/or the initial people receiving the rumour absorb it without paying too much attention to who said it to them.

It's also the roll that is made *when the action is taken*. So (a) it represents the action and (b) there's no extra defence roll later (which would provide metagame information if a player character would spreading the gossip.)

---

That said, the goal is to find the **source** of the rumours. It isn't to seek out the rumours, you've got them already! I'd be looking at **[seeker's] Investigation vs. [source's original roll of] Courtier(Gossip)** here.

Comment: Investigation with what specialty?

Comment: Interrogation since, I assume, it would involve talking to people to learn where they got the story from. I'd allow the Gossip emphasis to be lifted from Courtier into Investigation too.

Comment: So you propose **Investigation (Interrogation)/Perception  vs. [source's original roll of] Courtier(Gossip)/Awareness** as the main roll, using Courtier(gossip) as a different source for the emphasis?